# Send Email via Flow that will show Last Opened

Tags: email-template

I have a classic email template that contains a holiday card image.  I can send the email template via an email alert in a flow.  It works well.  However, it logs the email in the contact's activity log in the old task format.  However, if I am on a contact record and insert the template and sent it to the contact, the email is captured as an email in activity that shows the Last Opened by feature.

I want to be able to send an email template via a flow and have it captured in a contact's activity and show the Last Opened date.

I believe the bottom line is that I want to be able to send an enhanced email via a Flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a flow's email alert on a custom object by populating an email field on the custom object and then sending from that object.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pSVdQAM) on Idea Exchange:

> Only Emails that are on the Email Message object would be displayed there... Email Alerts are not stored anywhere.

My guess is you could create an Apex @invokablemethod that sends an EmailMessage linked to your record and use that in your flow instead of the email alert.

Comment: The org that I am working with is a Professional version without API access.  I am wondering if I can send an email via Flow via an email alert and then manually create a record in the Email Message object.  I am not sure what lets Salesforce know when an email has been opened.  I am looking at the EmailMessage object fields and nothing is standing out to me as to how to do this.  Thoughts on whether I can manually create an EmailMessage record & track email message opens?